# Django Malformed String in view due to boolean variations

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views

I am trying to read some variables from a post command sent from javascript. When i print the variables received in my view, the following is received:

```
>>> print request.body
{"p":"testprd","cash":false,"cheque":true,"debit":false,"credit":true}
```

Now **cash, cheque, debit** and **credit** are *checkboxes* in the html and hence the values `"true"` and `"false"`. But python reads only `"True"` and `"False"` and thus when i tried the following, i got a `Malformed String` error:

```
def post(self, request):
    x = ast.literal_eval(request.body)
    p = x.get('p')
    cash = x.get('cash')
    cheque = x.get('cheque')
    debit = x.get('debit')
    credit = x.get('credit')
```

This is how i am making my post from JS:

```
var variables = {
        "p": p,
        "cash": cash,
        "cheque": cheque,
        "debit": debit,
        "credit": credit
    }
    $http.post('postproductdetail/', variables).then(function(response){
    }, function(response){
        alert('Unable to save Product');
    });
```

So how do i get rid of this issue?

Comment: Why don't use `request.POST`?

Comment: u meant the QueryDict?

Comment: Yup, you can work with it as a regular `dict`.

Comment: but when i tried print request.POST.get('cash'), it was returning me a None

Comment: the method is a POST.

Comment: just made an edit if that helps..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually posting JSON. So you should decode it to Python dict via the json decoder in your view rather than calling `literal_eval`.

```
x = json.loads(request.body)
```